# How to display an image by using its url?

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

Hi guys i want to display an image that is on the web by using its URL. This is my code:

```
public class LasVegas extends ActionBarActivity {

    //variable del toolbar o app_bar
    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    //variable del view de la camara
    private ImageView viewCamVegas;
    //variable del bitmap(hace la imagen del url)
    private Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //se "liga" la apariencia (xmls) a el codigo de java
        setContentView(R.layout.las_vegas);

        //le pasamos el view de el xml a la variable viewCamVegas
        viewCamVegas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camaraVegas);

        bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg");

        //se le pasa la imagen de el url al imageview
        viewCamVegas.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        //se le da el valor de el app_bar o toolbar que creamos a la variable toolbar que creamos en esta clase
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);


        //se aclara que no se va a usar el toolbar de android si no el mio (app_bar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Vamos a crear el boton back de el toolbar para regresar a la actividad principal
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        //si se cliquea pico en el menu popout de la appbar y placa despliega la actividad de el pico y placa
        if (id == R.id.picoplaca) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PicoPlaca.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        //si se cliquea contacto en el menu popout de la appbar despliega la actividad contacto
        else if (id == R.id.contactomenu) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contacto.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        //Si se preciona el boton hacia atras, te lleva a la actividad principal
        if (id == android.R.id.home)

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    //metodo Bitmap que va a poner la imagen de el url
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)

    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }



}
```

It perfectly compiles, but when I run it, the image view that is supposed to display the image by URL is empty; it doesn't show anything at all.

How can I solve this?

Comment: **Please** use an existing, tested library for downloading and displaying images, such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). Among other things, they will do this work asynchronously. Your code is going to try to do network I/O on the main application thread, which means it will crash on Android 4.0+ with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) ? Just add the `.jar` file to your `libs` folder and add the following line to your code:

```
Picasso.with(this)
.load("http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg")
.into(viewCamVegas);
```

Comment: i'm actually trying to display an ip camera streaming on it, do you think picasso is still a viable solution for this? @Zygotelnit

Comment: Not really ... although I'm not clear on what you mean by "ip camera streaming" ... it would not be possible to display such data in an `ImageView`, whereas Picasso is for dealing with `ImageView` and `Bitmap` objects.